# Meaning of "Flags" column in dnsmasq log output

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I sent a SIGUSR1 signal to the dnsmasq process to make it write statistics to the system log. Here's an excerpt of what dnsmasq wrote to the system log:

```
daemon.info dnsmasq[1]: Host                                     Address                        Flags      Expires
daemon.info dnsmasq[1]: www.youtube.com                                                         CF         Fri Dec  1 18:30:12 2023
daemon.info dnsmasq[1]: ip6-allnodes                   ff02::1                                  6FRI   H
daemon.info dnsmasq[1]: contacts.fe.apple-dns.net      17.248.224.2                             4F         Fri Dec  1 18:31:07 2023
daemon.info dnsmasq[1]: play.google.com                192.178.50.78                            4F         Fri Dec  1 18:33:33 2023
...
```

This appears to be a list of unexpired DNS cache entries. However, I don't understand the meaning of the "Flags" column. What do "CF", "6FRI   H", and "4F" mean?